# Проблемы с валидацией формы

Tags: javascript

Есть форма для заполнения данных. Есть её валидация. Проблема в том, что если я заполняю форму верно сразу же, т.е. как только открывается страница, то всё впорядке. НО! Если я сначала заполняю форму неверно и пытаюсь отправить её, мне показываются ошибки (всё по плану). А вот после того как я верно заполнил поля, мне всё равно выдаётся инфа о неверном заполнении, но из-за того что поле

```
validity.customError === true
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Code:

```js
var setNotice = function (checkResult) {
  checkResult.forEach(function (arrElement) {
    var field = arrElement.field;
    var notice = arrElement.notice;
    field.setCustomValidity(notice);
  });
};
var getNotice = function (element) {
  var validity = element.validity;
  var notices = [];
  if (validity.valueMissing === true) {
    notices.push('This field is must being filled');
  }
  if (validity.typeMismatch === true) {
    notices.push('Input correct ' + element.type + '!');
  }
  if (validity.tooShort === true) {
    notices.push('Input value is too short. Minimum length is ' + element.minLength + ' characters!');
  }
  if (validity.tooLong === true) {
    notices.push('Input value is too long. Minimum length is ' + element.maxLength + ' characters!');
  }
  // if (validity.stepMismatch === true) { }
  if (validity.rangeUnderflow === true) {
    notices.push('Input value is too small. Minimum value is ' + element.min + ' roubles!');
  }
  if (validity.rangeOverflow === true) {
    notices.push('Input value is too great. Maximum value is ' + element.max + ' roubles!');
  }
  if (validity.patternMismatch === true) {
    notices.push('Input value mismatch with pattern!');
  }
  // if (validity.customError === true) { }
  // if (validity.badInput === true) { }
  return notices.join('; ');
};
var checkValidity = function (elements) {
  var checkResult = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].validity.valid) {
      continue;
    }
    checkResult.push({
      field: elements[i],
      notice: getNotice(elements[i])
    });
  }
  return checkResult;
};
var isValid = function (checkResult) {
  return (Object.keys(checkResult).length === 0) ? true : false;
};
var onSendFormClicked = function (evt) {
  var elementsInput = getFormInputs();
  var checkResult = checkValidity(elementsInput);
  if (isValid(checkResult)) {
    showSuccessSendInfo();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    setNotice(checkResult);
  }
};
```

Comment: Как у вас валидация начинает работать, какие события обрабатываете?

Comment: Добавил код. Обрабатываю одно событие по нажатию на кнопку отправки формы